# python athena calculate total number of output rows

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I need to get total number of output rows returned by Athena.

```
    status = 'RUNNING'
    while status in ['QUEUED', 'RUNNING']:
        response_get_query_details = athena.get_query_execution(
            QueryExecutionId=query_execution_id
        )

        status = (
            response_get_query_details.get("QueryExecution", {})
            .get("Status", {})
            .get("State", "NA")
        )

        if status in ("FAILED", "CANCELLED", "NA"):
            raise Exception(f"Athena Query Failed: {failure_reason}")
        elif status == 'SUCCEEDED':
            query_stats = response_get_query_details['QueryExecution']['Statistics']
            total_rows = query_stats['OutputRows'] <<--- `outputRows` is not available
            return total_rows
```

There's only `DataScannedInBytes` in the statistics.

```
{'EngineExecutionTimeInMillis': 9799, 'DataScannedInBytes': 1090182, 'TotalExecutionTimeInMillis': 9991, 'QueryQueueTimeInMillis': 164, 'QueryPlanningTimeInMillis': 8860, 'ServiceProcessingTimeInMillis': 28}
```

Is there a way to calculate total number of rows from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get_query_runtime_statistics()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.get_query_runtime_statistics) API call returns **the number of rows returned by the query**:

```json
{
    'QueryRuntimeStatistics': {
        'Timeline': {
            'QueryQueueTimeInMillis': 123,
            'QueryPlanningTimeInMillis': 123,
            'EngineExecutionTimeInMillis': 123,
            'ServiceProcessingTimeInMillis': 123,
            'TotalExecutionTimeInMillis': 123
        },
        'Rows': {
            'InputRows': 123,
            'InputBytes': 123,
            'OutputBytes': 123,
            'OutputRows': 123   <-- Here!
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_query_runtime_statistics` is not available for this client. Upon looking into the doc I found this `"Stage-level input and output row count and data size statistics are not shown when a query has row-level filters defined in Lake Formation."`. What does this mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not available for this client"?

Comment: `Athena... has no attribute `get_query_runtime_statistics`

Comment: ok this could be an issue with boto3 version

Comment: You can use `import boto3; print(boto3.__version__)` to discover the version. The current version is `1.26.71`. It that is not the problem, please show us the code that generates the "has no attribute" error.

Comment: thanks.. updated to the latest `v1.26.71` and this is fine now. :)